# GitHub self-hosted runner appears offline on codespace start up

Tags: github, github-codespaces

## Context

In my `.devcontainer.json` file I have `postCreateCommand` and `postStartCommand` jobs that point to `startup.sh` script. My idempotent `.startup.sh` script start github's self-hosted runner with `nohup` process - that way the runner runs in background and don't stop it accidentally.

**.devcontainer.json**

```json
"postCreateCommand": ".devcontainer/scripts/startup.sh",
"postStartCommand": ".devcontainer/scripts/startup.sh"
```

**startup.sh**

```bash
echo "Configure GitHub Runner"
./config.sh remove --token $SELF_HOSTED_RUNNER_TOKEN
./config.sh --url https://github.com/$GITHUB_REPOSITORY --unattended --token $SELF_HOSTED_RUNNER_TOKEN --name $RepositoryName --labels "self-hosted,Linux,X64,$RepositoryName"

echo "Start GitHub Runner"
nohup ./run.sh & > _diag/runner.log
```

## Problem

When I create a new GitHub Codespace, my runners appear in `Offline` mode. However, when I run my `startup.sh` script from within my GitHub Codespace manually then it appears `Idle` as expected.

## Question

How to start GitHub self-hosted runner on devcontainer startup so, it's in `Idle` state every time I start/restart my codespace?

Answer (score 1):

I found the cause of this insane behavior. Apparently, github self-hosted runner doesn't like to be run as a background process! The problem was `&` in `nohup` command.

I ended up running my `startup.sh` script only with `postStartCommand` and,  github's self hosted runner `run.sh` script without `nohup`

#### Don't

```
nohup ./run.sh &
```

#### Do

```
./run.sh
```